# How to use R.resource in Java from ANE?

Tags: java, air, jar

everyone,sorry for my poor English..

I want to ask "What is the appropriate way to manage resource in ANE"??

I have exported jar-library,and made ANE then called from Air Mobile.
(I check include-resource-option when I export from eclipse.)
When I debug on device,it seems that the Java's R.resource is overrided by R.resource air made.

For example,I have added FREFunction returns resource-value.
If I refer and display string.app_name,It shows string.app_name of Air-Project's name .
After I added string.test to resouce in Java,and then display it from apk,there is no value.

What is the appropriate way to manage resource in ANE.

Reference:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air/extensions/vibration.html

```
public class Native_xxxxxxx implements FREFunction {

    private Resources res;

    public FREObject call(FREContext arg0, FREObject[] arg1) {

        try {

            Activity activity = arg0.getActivity();

            res = activity.getResources();

            return FREObject.newObject(res.getString(arg0.getResourceId("string.app_name ")));

            //return FREObject.newObject(res.getString(arg0.getResourceId("string.test"))) ;

            //return FREObject.newObject(res.getString(R.string.test));

        } catch ( Exception ex ) {

        }
        return null;

    }

}
```

Additional Information:

I have realized one thing,
after unzip .jar,it contains res-folder,
but after unzip .ane it doesn't contains res-folder.

I guess,It means adt command fails to include res folder.

my command:
adt -package -target ane ANExxx.ane ane.xml -swc ANExxx.swc -platform Android-ARM library.swf res Nativexxx.jar -platform default library.swf Nativexxx.jar

Comment: Is this question related with Android development as well?

Comment: Yes,I work for running android native code in adobe air.

Answer (score 0):

create a build folder as this:

```
/build
    /ane
        myANEInterface.swc
        catalog.xml
        extension.xml
        /Android-ARM
                    myANE.jar
                    library.swf
                    /res
                        resource.xml
```

Note res folder has a copy of your resource files.

Then use this from outside of build folder, please note dot at the end:

```
adt -package -storetype PKCS12 -keystore ./mycert.p12 -storepass yourpassword -tsa none -target ane myANE.ane ./build/ane/extension.xml -swc ./build/ane/myANEinterface.swc -platform Android-ARM -C ./build/ane/Android-ARM/ .
```